# How to address fields with special characters in dynamic object?

Tags: c#

I am converting a XML document into JSON and from there into a dynamic object:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = 
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

Now most of the resulting `dynamic`looks fine. But there are a few special cases which I don't how to address:

- The root `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` element ends up like this in the JSON (and hence the dynmaic object):

  `"?xml": {"@version": "1.0","@encoding": "utf-8"}`
- Another XML tag which contains (only) attributes goes into this:

  `"MyTag": {"@id": "1339", "@creationTime": "2017-11-08T19:43:09.031Z"}`

So how can I adress `?xml` or `@id` in my dynamic object?

`string id = obj.Tag.@id` does not work of course. Neither with `obj.?xml`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: thats an xml declaration.

Comment: Try: `obj.GetType().GetProperty("@id").GetValue(obj, null)`. This is using reflection. I don't know if DeserializeObject creates properties or fields though

Comment: @d--b: Reflection won't see those properties, as they're not real properties on the type.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: I thought `dynamic` was a keyword to make reflection calls shorter. What happens under the hood when you do: `obj.prop`?

Comment: @d--b: It *can* just do normal reflection - but if the type implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, it can react however it wants. It can "pretend" to have properties that aren't known about until execution time - but the CLR type doesn't have those properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the indexer instead of treating it as a propertly:

```
dynamic xml = obj["?xml"];
dynamic tagId = obj.Tag["@id"];
```

Having said that, I'd personally use LINQ to XML directly rather than going via JSON and dynamic typing.

Comment: Adding [LINQ to XML Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview)

Comment: In my case I basically want to store the whole XML input file in a JSON object afterwards. So I only need to do some cleanup here. Thus I'm not sure if Linq XML would be easier?!

Comment: @silent: I'm not really sure what you mean by "a JSON object". But it does feel like there should be a better way of doing this. For example, you could load the document as an `XDocument`, do the cleanup with it still as XML, *then* do whatever deserialization you're talking about.

Comment: @DaisyShipton sorry, I meant Json Document. Essentially I'm writing it into an Azure Cosmos DB. So for this to be a somewhat normal JSON document, I want to get rid of all the XML specifics in there and also remove any "@" chars in front of properties (which were attributes in the XML)

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case you can access it like this:

```
string id = obj.Tag["@id"]
var xml = obj["?xml"];
```

Because underlying dynamic object also has indexer (underlying object is json.net `JObject`). Note that in general case it's not true:

```
dynamic obj = new {a = 1};  
var a = obj["a"]; // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understood what you wanted, but this is a sample of something similar that I did a while ago.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); // your XML
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/"); // Your XML Nodes


Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>(); // your 
dictionary Key, Value

foreach (XmlNode n in nodes) { 
    dic.Add(n.Name, n.InnerText); // name is your tag and InnerText or InnerXML is your value
}

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
```

Hope it help!